# mostrar un array en un metodo

Tags: java, array

Tengo  un método que debe mostrar los elementos de un *array*, y hay que convertir el `ArrayList` que contiene los elementos en un array. Este paso ya lo tengo, pero ahora debo retornar el *array* con los elementos que contiene.

No entiendo cómo devolver un *array* si para mostrarlo necesito un bucle `for each`, y al retornar debería mostrar el elemento, pero claro los elementos son de tipo `Producto` y yo necesito devolver un *array* de tipo `Producto[]`.

La verdad estoy un poco desesperado y frustrado. Adjunto código. Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

```
public class Productos {

    private static final String NOMBRE_POR_DEFECTO = " -- SIN NOMBRE -- ";
    private String nombre;
    private String descripcion;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {

        if (nombre == null) {

            nombre = NOMBRE_POR_DEFECTO;

        } else {

            this.nombre = nombre;

        }
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    private final String codigo;
    {

        char letraCodigo = (char) ((new Random()).nextInt(26) + 'A');
        int numeroCodigo = ((new Random())).nextInt(1000 - 100 + 1) + 100;
        codigo = letraCodigo + "-" + numeroCodigo;
    }

    public Productos(String nombre, String descripcion) {

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public Productos(String descripcion) {

        this.nombre = NOMBRE_POR_DEFECTO;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;

    }
```

public class RepositorioProductos {

```
private static ArrayList<Productos> arrayListProductos;

static {

    arrayListProductos = new ArrayList<>();

}

public static void addProducto(Productos producto) {
    arrayListProductos.add(producto);

}

public static void editProducto(int posicion, Productos producto) {
    arrayListProductos.set(posicion, producto);
}

public static void removeProducto(Productos producto) {
    arrayListProductos.remove(producto);
}

public static Productos getProducto(int posicion) {
    return arrayListProductos.get(posicion);
}

public static int findProducto(Productos producto) {
    return arrayListProductos.indexOf(producto);
}

public static Productos[] findAllProductos() {

    Productos[] arrayProductos = arrayListProductos.toArray(new Productos[arrayListProductos.size()]);
    
    
    return arrayProductos;

}



public static Productos[] findProductosByNombre(String nombre) {

    Productos[] arrayProductos = arrayListProductos.toArray(new Productos[arrayListProductos.size()]);

    return arrayProductos;

}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       RepositorioProductos rp = new RepositorioProductos();
       
       //añadimos productos al arrayList
       
       Productos p1 = new Productos("pantalon","pantalon vaquero negro");
       Productos p2 = new Productos("mochila", "mochila verde estudiante");
       Productos p3 = new Productos("corbata", "corbata color azul");
       Productos p4 = new Productos("bañador naranja sin nombre");
       
       rp.addProducto(p1);
       rp.addProducto(p2);
       rp.addProducto(p3);
       rp.addProducto(p4);
       
       Productos p5 = new Productos("cartera", "cartera de piel negra");
       //editamos el producto con indice 1 y le agregamos este nuevo producto
       rp.editProducto(1,p5);
       
       //eliminamos el producto perteneciente al indice indicado por parametros
       rp.removeProducto(p3);
       
       System.out.println(rp.getProducto(2));
       
       System.out.println(rp.findProducto(p4));
       
       System.out.println(RepositorioProductos.findAllProductos());
       

           
           
       }
```

Comment: No veo claro de dónde sacas los elementos en ese método ¿? Pero sería más simple declarar el método así: **`public static ArrayList<Productos> findAllProductos() {`** y dentro del método: 1º) declaras tu lista de objetos del tipo `Productos` con: **`ArrayList<Productos> arrayProductos = new ArrayList<Productos>();`** 2º)   usas `add` para agregar cada objeto: **`arrayProductos.add(new Productos( ...aqui los parametros...);`** pones tantos `add` como sean necesarios y 3º) retornas la lista: **`return arrayProductos;`** Lo que no entiendo es de dónde obtendrías los objetos `Productos` ¿?

Comment: Hola,  si es que me piden que cree una propiedad de tipo ArrayList<Productos> y luego unos metodos donde uso el add, remove, delete, entre otros. Entonces en la clase del main llamo a los metodos que agregan los productos y demás y ahi es donde se agregan al ArrayList pero me estoy volviendoloco porque porque me "obligan" a devolverlo como array y he probado bucles, y diferentes cosas pero nunca me da como resultado un elemento de tipo array para poder retornar en ese metodo findAllProductos();  Muchas Gracias por mostrar interes en esta duda. Un saludo.

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo que comentas. Por favor pulsa en [edit]  y explica mejor el contexto. Realmente no le veo demasiado sentido a lo que intentas hacer, más aún si dices que ya en el `main` construyes un `ArrayList` con elementos del tipo `Productos` ¿? ¿Qué es lo que habría que hacer luego con esa lista? Por cierto, respeta la convención de nombre en Java, los nombres de entidades deben ir en singular, `Producto`, no `Productos` eso presta a confusión, pues un producto es una entidad singular, no plural.

Comment: Hola de nuevo he puesto el código en su totalidad para que se entienda. Para mi sería mas facil hacer lo que dices pero tengo que hacer ese método tal cual

Comment: Eso ya lo tienes: `public static Productos[] findAllProductos() { Productos[] arrayProductos = arrayListProductos.toArray(new Productos[arrayListProductos.size()]); for (Productos obj : arrayProductos) {
System.out.print(obj.getNombre() + " "); } return arrayProductos; }` he puesto dentro del método un `for` para que compruebes que se muestra el nombre de cada producto.

Answer (score 0):

Modifica tu método `findAllProductos()`, al obtener el array itera sobre este array para mostrar el nombre de cada objeto `Producto` usando el método `getNombre()` :

```
public static Productos[] findAllProductos() { 
 Productos[] arrayProductos = arrayListProductos.toArray(new Productos[arrayListProductos.size()]); 
   for (Productos producto : arrayProductos) { 
     System.out.print(producto.getNombre() + "\n "); 
    }
 return arrayProductos; 
}
```